# "CPTAnimation.m" Too many arguments to function call, expected 0, have 3

Tags: core-plot

Today my boss give me one App, this app builded on IOS SDK 8.1 and xocde 6.1.the Podfile include:

```
Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, ‘7.0’
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
def import_pods
pod 'AFNetworking', '~>2.5.0'
pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.7.1'
pod 'CocoaLumberjack', '~> 1.9'
pod 'EasyMapping', '~> 0.6.3'
pod 'ReactiveCocoa', '~> 2.3.1'
pod 'libextobjc', '~>0.4.1'
pod 'CorePlot', '~>1.5.1'
#    pod 'ActionSheetPicker-3.0', '~>1.3.5'
#    pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.9'
end
```

After i finished pod install, run this apps, the error message was coming like this:
setterMethod(boundObject, boundSetter, buffer); Too many arguments to function call, expected 0, have 3
setterMethod(boundObject, boundSetter, tweenedValue);Too many arguments to function call, expected 0, have 3
and this issue from "CPTAnimation.m" file
anyone can tell me whats happen for this,please help me to fix it.thanks so munch.

Comment: I added this podfile to a new project. I'm not seeing this error, even with pedantic warnings enabled.

Comment: i fix this after i re-install cocopads.

Answer (score 2):

The fix is here: https://github.com/IngmarStein/core-plot/commit/3413d8b7fa382921a918e7801a22e614a17b8bbf

You'll need to edit the CorePlot code in your project, or else you can use the pre-release version 2.0 from GitHub rather than from CocoaPods.

Comment: Helped me in this sequence:
1. Switched in Podfile to `pod 'CorePlot', :git => 'https://github.com/IngmarStein/core-plot.git', :branch => 'release-2.0'`.
2. Applied changes from 2nd and 3rd code chunks from `https://github.com/IngmarStein/core-plot/commit/3413d8b7fa382921a918e7801a22e614a17b8bbf`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm wondering what's your cocoapods's version?

In my case, cocoapods 0.34.4 is OK while cocoapods 0.36.0 suffers the same issue. Since I also tagged the CorePlot as 1.5.1 in my Podfile, I guess the difference laid in the way cocoapods modifies your Xcode workspace.

In the end, I downgraded my cocoapods to 0.34.4.

Comment: In my case. 0.36.4 is still not OK, I must downgraded to 0.35.0.